# Create a list of 100 integers whose values equal their indexes

Tags: python, list

Create a list of 100 integers whose value and index are the same, e.g.

```
mylist[0] = 0, mylist[1] = 1, mylist[2] = 2, ...
```

Here is my code.

```
x_list=[]

def list_append(x_list):
    for i in 100:
        x_list.append(i)

        return(list_append())
    print(x_list)
```

Comment: how about `range(100)`?

Comment: `[_ for _ in range (100)]`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since nobody else realised you're using Python 3, I'll point out that you should be doing `list(range(100))` to get the wanted behaviour.

Comment: How can you tell that OP is using py3? Because he uses a parenthesized term after `print`? He does this too after `return`.

Comment: @Hyperboreus yes I am using 3

Answer (score 6):

Use range() for generating such a list

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> range(10)[5]
5
```

Answer (score 2):

`for i in 100` doesn't do what you think it does. `int` objects are not iterable, so this won't work. The for-loop tries to iterate through the object given.

If you want to get a list of numbers between 0-100, use [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range):

```
for i in range(100):
    dostuff()
```

The answer to your question is pretty much `range(100)` anyway:

```
>>> range(100)[0]
0
>>> range(100)[64]
64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `range(100)`, but it seems that you are probably looking to make the list from scratch, so there you can use `while`:

```
x_list=[]
i = 0
while i<100:
    x_list.append(i)
    i += 1
```

Or you could do this recursively:

```
def list_append(i, L):
    L.append(i)
    if i==99:
        return L
    list_append(i+1, L)

x_list = []
list_append(0, x_list)
print x_list
```

Comment: The -1 wasn't me but it's probably because you forgot to increment i. When you -1 at least give a reason plz...

Answer (score 1):

Also can use List Comprehensions, like

```
[x for x in range(100)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import `numpy` you could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

x_list = np.arange(0, 100).tolist()
```

Should work in python2.7 and python3.x

Answer (score -1):

```
import random
data1=[]
def f(x):
    return(random.randrange(0,1000))
for x in range (0,100):
    data1.append(f(x))

data1
```

Comment: This is not what the question asked for

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25983483)